# Are symmetric and $\Delta$-metric common terminologies?

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces

[In these notes](https://math631spring2011.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/metricandmetrizablespaces.pdf) on metric spaces, the author also defined something known as "symmetric", and $\Delta$-metric.

I have never seen these terminologies before. Are these terms standard usage? Can someone provide an additional, authoratative reference to these objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience the author’s *symmetric* is more often called a *semimetric*, though I have seen the auther’s term used before. For example, Gary Gruenhage uses it in **Definition** $\mathbf{9.5}$ of ‘Generalized Metric Spaces’ in *Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology*, K. Kunen & J.E. Vaughan, eds., though he uses the usual term *semimetric space* for a set endowed with a symmetric/semimetric.

I’ve not seen the author’s term $\Delta$-*metric* before; the usual term is *quasimetric*. You can find these and other terms for generalized metrics [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Generalized_metrics). Gary’s article defines quasimetrics in **Definition** $\mathbf{10.1}$.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is a standard way to define a metric $d$ from a quasimetric $\rho$ (like defining a metric from a pseudometric by a quotient construction), namely define $d$ by $d(x,y)=\max\{\rho(x,y), \, \rho(y,x)\},$ which is often called the symmetrization of the quasimetric $\rho.$ A "naturally occurring" example of this is the Hausdorff metric being the symmetrization of either of two possible quasimetrics, the quasimetrics being obvious when you look at the definition of the Hausdroff metric and compare it with the symmetrization of a quasimetric.